# Ejecutar If dentro de un For Each

Tags: php, mariadb, if

Estoy haciendo un proyecto utilizando: Php, css, html, mariadb "mysql"

Estoy intentando ejecutar una sentencia If dentro de un bucle ForEach, pero el "if" solo se ejecuta en la primera ejecucion del Foreach, en el resto se ejecuta todo, excepto lo del If. No entiendo que esta pasando.

Aqui mi codigo:

Como podran observar, tengo unas filas y columnas para mostrar: 
primero: un identificador, 
segundo: informacion general del correspondiente identificador
tercero: en una barra de progreso muestro cierta informacion.
cuarto: ejecuto un if para determinar que tipo de informacion mostrar en otra barra de progreso.
quinto: muestro dos fechas

Esta imagen muestra como deberian de verse todos los resultados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta imagen muestra que no se carga la segunda barra de progreso en todos los resultados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui mi codigo:

```
<?php
                foreach ($records as $r) {
                    $p = 100 - $r->PT;
                    ?>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
                                <a href="Consultas.php?OT=<?php echo escape($r->OT); ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button" style="margin-top: 20px;"><?php echo escape($r->OT). ' '; ?><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h6><?php echo escape($r->ingenio); ?></h6>
                                <h5><strong><?php echo escape($r->descripcion); ?></strong></h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 20px">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:<?php echo escape($r->PT); ?>%"><?php echo escape($r->PT); ?>%</div>
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width:<?php echo escape($p); ?>%"><?php echo escape($p); ?>%</div>
                                </div>
                                <?php 
                                    echo escape($r->tMaza);
                                    $var = escape($r->tMaza);
                                    if ($var = "CMA") {
                                        include_once 'PG_MazaConvencional.php';
                                    } else if ($var = "CCB") {
                                        include_once 'PG_MazaConvencional_CascoBurdo.php';
                                    } else if ($var = "CCL") {
                                        include_once 'PG_MazaConvencional_CascoLiso.php';
                                    } else if ($var = "CCR") {
                                        include_once 'PG_MazaConvencional_CascoRayado.php';
                                    } else if ($var = "HMA") {
                                    } else if ($var = "HCB") {
                                    } else if ($var = "HCL") {
                                    } else if ($var = "HCR") {
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
                                <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo escape($r->fecha_alta); ?></span> <br>
                                <span class="label label-danger"><?php echo escape($r->f_e_term); ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ($var == "CMA") {
            include_once 'PG_MazaConvencional.php';
```

intenta colocar los dos signos = en los if e if else, ya que con uno estas asignando un valor a la variable y no comparandola.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jesus Solis, ya he hecho lo que acertadamente comentas pero el "problema" persiste, solo me muestra la segunda barra de progreso en la primera ejecucion.

Comment: ya imprimiste con print_r(); el array $records para verificar si el contenido es correcto?

Comment: Yo haría también `echo $var;`  antes de los `if` para ver lo que hay en dicha variable realmente.

Comment: Gracias por sus sugerencias, de hecho esta impreso el array, si alcanza a apreciar en las imagenes se puede ver el CMA. y para esos dos casos es correcto dicho display de la variable. Sigo buscando solucion...